# 全角で入力すると表示されない

Tags: monaca

pタグの中などに日本語の文章を書いてenterすると文字が消えます。半角で文字を打つと表示されるのですが、これは普通のことなのでしょうか？

当方、プログラミング初心者の為教えて頂けたら幸いですよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 普通のことではありません。原因は私には見当も付きません。使用しているOS、ブラウザ、日本語入力システム、などを質問に追記すればアドバイズをくれる方もいるかも知れません。（酷い不具合ですから、直接サポートに問合せた方がよいかも知れませんね）

Comment: Monacaのお問い合わせ : https://ja.monaca.io/support/inquiry.html

Comment: サポートの方に問い合わせしました。

Comment: これはmonacaのWEBIDEの話ですか？

Comment: [MonacaクラウドIDEのエディターで日本語入力が表示されない事象について（Google Chrome 53.0.2785.101m）](https://ja.monaca.io/headline/fault.html)

Answer (score 2):

以下の経緯で解決ずみです。

> 2016/9/12 01:30 UTC
>       Google Chrome 53.0.2785.101mでMonacaクラウドIDEのエディター上に日本語入力をした際、エンターキーを押すと入力した文字が表示されない事象が発生しております。
>
> この事象は、Google Chrome(53.0.2785.101m)の不具合によるものになります。
>
> 回避策といたしましては、日本語入力後、エンターキーを押し、文字が消えた後に、再度エンターキーまたはスペースキーを押すことで表示されます。

---

> 2016/9/12 22:30 UTC
>       パッチを適用しました。現在は、正常に日本語入力をご利用いただけます。
>       入力した文字が表示されない場合は、一度ブラウザーのキャッシュをクリアーをお願いいたします。

https://ja.monaca.io/headline/fault.html